# Актуальные книги по Ассемблеру

Tags: ассемблер

Посоветуйте книги по Ассемберу, что недавно вышли и представляются актуальными

Comment: Собственно, со времен вопроса [Есть ли книги по assembler за 2013 год?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276502/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-assembler-%d0%b7%d0%b0-2013-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4?rq=1), например, ничего не изменилось. Ассемблер x86 можно изучать по книгам 20-летней давности. Если нужно что-то большее - смотрим справочник от Intel.

Comment: @Vlad  Сами по себе книги по ассемблеру не являются актуальными, так как это крайне редкое исключение, когда используется язык ассемблера. Разве что он используется где-нибудь для микропроцессоров. Поэтому актуальность ассемблера зависит от актуальности аппаратных средств.:)

Comment: Да по большому счёту весь ассемблер укладывается в изучение набора инструкций процессора. Он не такой уж и большой, вполне справочные данные. Дальнейшее уже - изучение железа, особенностей и возможностей конкретного ассемблера (GAS, MASM, NASM, FASM, TASM...), ОС  и т.д.